# How do I delete old objects from collection with Kinvey Business Logic?

Tags: javascript, database, business-logic, kinvey

I have a collection called 'Events' at Kinvey and each event has a string formatted date to compare with current date. For example, I created the event "Party" and it has a startDate and endDate (iOS App). I want a custom Endpoint to delete the events that are not currently in this interval.

endDate looks like this: "2016-06-15 01:39:26 +0000"
I used modules.moment() to get current date and tried to compare with the endDate. If modules.moment() is greater than endDate, the event gets deleted from the db.

I want a custom EndPoint because this method will run scheduled all the time to always check if an event has ended. My knowledge on javascript is really poor and I tried many examples, but I don't seem to be even close to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandor,

Here is template code for your custom endpoint that might help you get started:

```
function onRequest(request, response, modules) {
    var logger = modules.logger;
    var events = modules.collectionAccess.collection('Events');
    var moment = modules.moment();

    events.remove({"endDate" : {"$lt": moment.toISOString()}},
        function(err,res)
        {
            if(err)
                {
                logger.error("Error " + err);
                return response.error(err);
                }
                else
                {
                return response.complete(200);
                }
    });
}
```

Once you test this business logic thoroughly, you can then schedule it using the “Schedule” option for this custom endpoint in the Kinvey Dashboard.

Thanks,
Pranav
Kinvey Support

Comment: I ended up solving my problem reading the documents provided by Kinvey. There wasn't a specific example, but I was able to apply it. Thank you so much, that worked for me as well and it was a cleaner code that the one I implemented. Thx! :)